# jquery jcarousel initcallback pass arguments with new value

Tags: jquery, callback, jcarousel

I am trying to load new items in jcarousel on AJAX request. I have a list of different music tracks and on the click event I pass the id of the track.

```
<ul id="itemTrack"> // Track items
 <li><a href="#" id="p1">Track 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" id="p2">Track 2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" id="p3">Track 3</a></li>
<ul>

<ul id="trackList"></ul> // carousel

$("#itemTrack a").bind("click", getSelectedTrack); // Click event bind on the track list

var theModelCarousel = null; // global variable assigned to null

function getSelectedTrack(e){
  var el = $(e.currentTarget), 
  currTrack = el.attr("id"), // Track ID
  apiurl = "ServiceLibrary/player/GetTrackList/" + currTrack;   // URL to get data
  $('#trackList').html(''); // Clear carousel list
  if (theModelCarousel != null){theModelCarousel.reset();}
  $('#trackList').jcarousel({
    vertical : true,
    scroll : 5,
    initCallback: function(carousel, state){
      if (state == 'init') {
        theModelCarousel = carousel;                
      }                 
      getListRequest(carousel, apiurl);
        }
    });
}

function getListRequest(carousel, apiurl){
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url : apiurl,
        dataType : 'jsonp',
        timeout : 8000,
        success : function(data){
            if(data){               
               // Add/Create Items HTML
            }else{

            }
        },
        error : function(err){
//          alert(err);
        }        
    });
};
```

On the above code if I click on the list item it will send the id(p1) to the 'apiurl' and gets the data but when I click on the another list item first time it will send the same old id(p1) to the ajax call and when I click second time it will send the correct id(p2). I can understand it will happen because of initcallback but did not get any resolution to clear/reset the 'apiurl' to the new value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reloadCallback for other upcoming requests

```
initCallback: function(carousel, state){        
      if (state == 'init') {
        theModelCarousel = carousel;
        getListRequest(carousel, apiurl);
      }
},
reloadCallback: function(carousel){
      getListRequest(carousel, apiurl);
}
```